# Able to login with any username if password space is blank, hardcoded php login form

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication, session-variables

my issue with this is that if you leave the password space blank and type in any username, for example 'potato' it still works to log in if the password space blank. The code is supposed to be hardcoded to two usernames and passwords and i guess there is something wrong with this line but can't figure out what.

```
if (isset($logins[$Username]) == $Password){
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
session_start(); /* Sessionen påbörjas här */
/* Submit för formuläret */
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
/* Tillgängliga lösenord och användarnamn */
$logins = array('Mattias' => '1','Mikael' => '2',);
/* Kolla och ge lösenord och användarnamn en ny variabel */
$Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username']:' ';
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password']:' ';
/* Kolla lösenord och användarnamn */
if (isset($logins[$Username]) == $Password){
    /* Vid lyckat försök skicka vidare till den lösenordsskyddade sidan    */     
    $_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] = $Username;
    header("Location:../admin/index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    /* Meddelande för fel lösenord/användarnamn */
    $felmeddelande = "<span style='color:red;'>Fel användarnamn eller   lösenord</span>";
}
}
?>
```

Tried this now and still does not work.. Any ideas? Anyone?

```
    if($logins[$_POST['Username']] == $_POST['Password']){
```

Is anyone able to answer this? In desperate need of help..

Comment: Where are the respective passwords for the usernames?

Comment: check my ans it's work perfect.

Comment: They are in this array: $logins = array('Mattias' => '1','Mikael' => '2',);

Comment: So the passwords are `1` and `2` for the respective users? @DouglasPettersson

Comment: Yes, 1 and 2 are the passwords.

Comment: Check my comment above @Qirel

Answer (score 0):

it's work perfect

```
if(isset($logins[$Username]))
{
    if ($logins[$Username] == $Password){
    /* Vid lyckat försök skicka vidare till den lösenordsskyddade sidan    */     
    $_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] = $Username;
    header("Location:../admin/index.php");
    exit();
    } else {
    /* Meddelande för fel lösenord/användarnamn */
    $felmeddelande = "<span style='color:red;'>Fel användarnamn eller   lösenord</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, your code does not work, the PHP page turns out blank when i insert this.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided in the other answer does work (however not flawlessly, *Undefined index* can appear and your username doesn't account for case-sensitivity ("Mattias" would work, but "MAttias" would not)), but I decided to post an answer explaining a bit more *why* his works and yours doesn't.

Your issue was this line

```
if (isset($logins[$Username]) == $Password){
```

as the `isset()` would return a boolean (true/false), and you can't check a boolean against a string. What would really happen here is that you enter a valid username, the statement would read `true == true`, which returns `true`. You already specify `$logins`, so you don't need to check if it's set or not.

You also have an issue should the username not be exactly like the one provided in your array (as per the other answer and your solution, it's *case-sensitive*).

With a slight modification, your code would look like this (provided that all names in the `$logins`-array has lower-case letters, but starts with capital-letter)

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    /* Tillgängliga lösenord och användarnamn */
    $logins = array('Mattias'=>'1', 'Mikael'=>'2');

    /* Kolla och ge lösenord och användarnamn en ny variabel */
    $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['Username'])) : '';
    $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

    /* Kolla lösenord och användarnamn */
    if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password) {
        /* Vid lyckat försök skicka vidare till den lösenordsskyddade sidan    */     
        $_SESSION['UserData']['Username'] = $Username;
        header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        /* Meddelande för fel lösenord/användarnamn */
        $felmeddelande = "<span style='color:red;'>Fel användarnamn eller lösenord</span>";
    }
}
```

I have tested this code, and it does work and will not produce any errors or warning (as that I could test for anyway), but if you encounter a problem implementing it, just shout out, and I'll try to help as best as I can.

You also had a space in your ternary-operator for `false`, this isn't really all that important, but it should (in my opinion) just be a blank string.